# SQL query to retrieve and display results

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL, can you please help me in retrieving the values as per below screen shot
[image]

and below is my backend query results.

[image]
For an instance, if DEG is 0, I should get the corresponding values(for height 5) ' i.e. (0.91,-0.29, -1.78,-2.05 etc). Similarly i have to group and display the values as per the screenshot L02Kj.png. Please let me know if you need more information

Comment: Priya, stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. You'll need to show that you've put some effort into this yourself. What have you tried so far? Is there a particular aspect you're stuck on?

Comment: Also, please do not post screenshots of your code; they're very difficult for us to work with. While you write your edit your question you have markdown capabilities and the convenient editor buttons available to you. Use them.

Comment: Sorry about that, I am stuck at the point wherein I have to sort all the '0's' in the DEG column , i have used the below query  select * from tableName where ENGINE_ID= 1950 AND CYLINDER_NO=1 ORDER BY CAST(LEVEL_NO AS INT ), can you please help me with this

Comment: @priya Please accept my reply as correct answer if it worked for you- so that other users can benefit: from knowing that the answer works and by having the question marked as Answered.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a dynamic pivot... here is a basic example using your data (some columns)

```
create table #TempTable (HEIGHT int, DEG int, COL_1 decimal(3,2))

insert into #TempTable
values
(5,0,0.91),
(15,0,-0.29),
(25,0,-1.78),
(5,160,3.17),
(15,160,1.15)


DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(Height)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Height as Height FROM #TempTable) AS Height

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT DEG as Angle, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM #TempTable
    PIVOT(SUM(COL_1) 
          FOR Height IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery


drop table #TempTable
```

Answer (score -1):

So you can use the below query to get what you want.
Assuming that your table is a table named `yourtable`, below query will give you your results.

```
select *
from
(
    select 
        deg+cast(angles_col_increment  as decimal(10,2))-10 as deg, 
        height, 
        angle_value 
    from
    (
        select 
            height,
            deg,
            [col_1] as [10],
            [col_2] as [20],
            [col_3] as [30],
            [col_4] as [40],
            [col_5] as [50],
            [col_6] as [60],
            [col_7] as [70],
            [col_8] as [80]
        from yourtable
    )s
    unpivot
    (
    angle_value for angles_col_increment in 
        (
        [10],[20],[30],[40],
        [50],[60],[70],[80]
        )
    )u
)s
pivot
(
    max(angle_value) for height in 
    (
      [5],[15],[25],[30.7] 
     )
 )p
```

<kbd>[**See live demo**](http://rextester.com/VZTEU89642)</kbd>

**Explanation:**

We've unpivoted the data in first step and also taken representative incremental angle values from the columns, which are later added to the deg column value as steps.
In next step we've pivoted the height column around the degrees to get the desired result.

In case you need to remove hard-coding around these angles/heights, please search for dynamic pivot/unpivot. There are tonnes of questions on SO on this.

Comment: Thanks Druv, I'll try it asap and let you know if it works.

Comment: @priya Thank you for the response. Let me know if it doesn't work