# how create a table in SQL with consecutive dates?

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a table that contains an `id` and multiple columns with date series. I mean

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS price_scrapp(
  id varchar(250),
  price_date1 date,
  price_date2 date,
  price_date3 date,
  price_date4 date,
  price_date5 date,
  price_date6 date
  #...
);
```

where `date1`, `date2`, `date3`,... must be dates generated  automatticaly. In my case must be the next 100 mondays.

```
"2017-11-27" "2017-12-04" "2017-12-11" "2017-12-18" "2017-12-25" "2018-01-01"
"2018-01-08" "2018-01-15" "2018-01-22" "2018-01-29" "2018-02-05" ...
```

The result must be

## Result

```
  price_2017-11-27 price_2017-12-04 price_2017-12-11 price_2017-12-18 price_2017-12-25 price_2018-01-01
           418467           199387           319402           359454           489591           112756
            88735           481561           310659           307747           291171           172578
           378819           298426            99965           302950            86076           431515
           167211           460831           360240           202222           393621           151283
           386879           108820           293997           234300           188834           108695
           257698           493266           306417           465134           317937           323749
```

Comment: I think you may come to regret modelling your data this way round

Comment: What do you recommend me for this case?

Comment: The problem is that the table will be updated each monday and I don't know a better way

Comment: Database tables are intended to grow vertically through the addition of rows, rather than horizontally through the addition of columns. If you want to represent data horizontally in a report (100 columns) when it's stored vertically (100 rows), you PIVOT the data as a function of generating the report

Comment: A better option would be for your table to have three columns: `id`, `date` & `price`. Also a `VARCHAR(250)` for an `id` column doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Date fields are designed to hold dates.

Comment: Listen to @CaiusJard on this... don't denormalize your data. You only need 3, maybe 4 columns here (an ID for what ever makes your data unique)

Comment: @PeterM thanks for the suggestion about `varchar(250)`

Comment: @scsimon I understand, but unfortunately, I must to add new data each week. The `id`is unique, the problem is not identify my data.

Comment: that's fine @HenryNavarro but insert it vertically, not horizontally. You can always pivot the data later.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, I'll give you an upvote in each comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a better set up...

- Use `INT` datatype for the `ID` **if possible**, and let SQL Server auto-increment this for you with the `IDENTITY` property
- Only have three columns, the `ID`, `price_date`, and the `price`
- Place a default value on the `price_date` which will insert the current date (for when ever you insert data) if you do not specify a date

Thus, it would look something like this:

```
create table price_scrapp ( id varchar(250)
                         ,price_date date default(getdate())
                         ,price decimal(8,2))


insert into price_scrapp (id,price)
values
('fo_12345678',418467)


--then the next week you insert more data...
insert into price_scrapp  (id,price)
values
('fo_12345678',546541.44)

--but today we want to specify a date....
insert into price_scrapp  (id,price_date,price)
values
('fo_12345678','20171101',400.13)

select * from price_scrapp
```

Then, if you really want to **present** the data in the way you have shown in the post, research Dynamic Pivot.

Here's a few examples:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45042349/6167855

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40598475/6167855

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45423065/6167855

http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/

Comment: I cannot use `int`for the `id`, because they has a structure like this: `fo_12345678`

Comment: ok, then make it varchar. everything else still applies. I'll edit

Comment: I'll take in account your suggestion. I'll give your answer as good. Thanks

Comment: Hi @scsimon, It's me again. It looks like  `(getdate()`doesn't work in mysql, do you have an equivalente in mysql, I am not using sql-server but you edited the tag.